# Getting the customer to schedule one more ride (carpool)

Tags: user-expectation, gamification

We are developing a carpool application. Once the ride is complete, I am trying to get them to schedule one more ride immediately. I feel something is missing in the experience, I am not able to pin point the feel. Do I need a more prominent HOME button ? Or should the text be more leading. This screen should also get them to feel really nice and good about themselves. I am kinda getting a mixed feeling here.

[image: driver completed the ride, earns km's]
[image: rider completed the ride, spent km's]

Comment: Some of the items on this page look selectable (the main buttons at the bottom) and others do not (because they are just plain text). I think you have a visual design challenge here. You need to make the 'schedule' option look selectable.

Comment: I was hoping that "HOME" would give that connect. Schedule is not selectable, its just text.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to make Buy/Redeem less prominent and replace HOME with "SCHEDULE YOUR NEXT CARPOOL" ?

Comment: If the goal is to get people to schedule a new ride, then the call to action text that you have should be what takes them there. Consider making it a button.

Comment: km is an abbreviation both for kilometer and for kilometers. No need to add the **'s**, that just makes it less readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If scheduling the next ride is the most important thing, then I'd strongly consider a visual redesign that gives that action more importance.

It makes sense to give them a congratulatory message, followed by a summary of where their balance stands, and then a call-to-action that engages them in your app.

Underneath that CTA you could place a button to return home, as well as your social and support messages. However, I'd also seriously consider making those messages far more succinct.

[image]

Comment: I have gone based on this. Great feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting something "human" on the screen: maybe their own profile picture, or even the profile pics of the people they carpooled with.

I agree with DA01 that the "schedule your next ride now" should be selectable and take users to the screen where they would naturally want to go. I can imagine people completing a ride and then saying: "Ok, when are we driving together again? Let's book it now"

Also, make the Facebook and e-mail links look click-able, or even better: just use a Facebook and e-mail icon instead of all the text.